Accessing folder shared in group not working
I have a user fes33 and I want to share its /home/fes33/Downloads folder to the postgres user by sharing it via the group fes33postgres.
(base) fes33@fes33:~$ getent group fes33postgres
fes33postgres:x:1002:postgres

The rights to the folder are fine:
(base) fes33@fes33:~$ ls -ad -l  Downloads
drwxrwx--- 5 fes33 fes33postgres 36864 May  7 08:50 Downloads

Yet when I go to my postgres account, I don't seem to have the rights to look into its contents.
(base) fes33@fes33:~$ sudo -iu postgres
postgres@fes33:~$ ls /home/fes33/Downloads
ls: cannot access '/home/fes33/Downloads': Permission denied
postgres@fes33:~$ 

Can anyone help?

since you don't directly access the user shell,
try:
# newgrp fes33postgres

then,
# ls /home/fes33/Downloads

